# Order by desc - issue

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a problem in `order by desc`. For example I want to order by desc the values of id which is 1-10. and here is the sample code

```
select stu_ID from student order by stu_ID desc
```

but from this I'll get this result

```
9
8
7
6
5
4
3
2
10
1
```

I want the result to be like this

```
10
9
8
7
6
5
4
3
2
1
```

help please thanks!

Comment: what is the datatype on `stu_id`?

Answer (score 8):

*The reason for that is because the **column is a string***. Right?

Try casting it to int,

```
SELECT * FROM tableName ORDER BY CAST(colName AS INT) DESC
```

or without casting, change the datatype of the column to `INT`, so you can directly sort the records without casting to another datatype,

```
SELECT * FROM tableName ORDER BY colName DESC
```

Comment: thanks! you're right the column is a string(varchar). Thank you so much this help me a lot!

Answer (score 3):

I assume these values are not `int` but `varchar`. So you should change the type to `int`. As long you can use `CAST`:

```
SELECT stu_id
FROM dbo.student
ORDER BY CAST(stu_id AS int) DESC
```

[**Here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/59a5d/2/1) is a demo with the incorrect(alphabetically) + correct(numerical) order.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
order by convert(int,id) desc
```

That should do it

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your column type is not numeric, but string.

Comment: You might want to explain how they fix the issue.

Comment: I do not have enough information for that. Is the column supposed to be numeric - then change its type, or otherwise he'll have to cast in many places. Is this an exception - then a cast will do.

Comment: @bluefeet What is the SO policy on this anyway? One day I get downvoted for giving a complete solution (a.k.a. "don't spoon-feed"), the next I get downvoted because I don't.

Comment: @uselpa there is no policy, users are free to down-vote for whatever reasons they feel appropriate. In this case, your answer should have been a comment, as you don't explain in any way how to work around it. This is similar to saying, "yep, your code is broken." I can't comment on your "don't spoon-feed" example. Can you show a link? In any case the folks who down-voted there might not even be the same people who commented about spoon feeding. And even if they were the same people, that's their choice and nobody's responsibility to hold them to some standard. Voting is anonymous for a reason.

Comment: You answer is more of a comment. If you elaborated on the problem like the other answers by showing how the OP could solve it, then you probably would not have received a downvote.